# iframe and header location issue

Tags: php, redirect, iframe, parent

I am using an iframe under which another small application is running on. In one certain page of the iframe, I try to redirect the url to parent's index page. But if I am using header('location:fullpath/index.php'). then it is redirecting to the mentioned page, but within the iframe. I need it will be opened beyond the iframe. Could you please help me to fix up this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use javascript and you have control over the target page, you can put this metatag at the top of the target page and it should open in a new window.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Window-target" CONTENT="_blank">
```

Here is a list of the other `CONTENT` options you can try as I'm not certain what `beyond the iframe` means.

```
Same Frame  -_self
Whole Page    -_top
New Window  -_blank
Parent Frame-_parent
```